# How to delete a field in Firestore document with flutter

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm making a Flutter application.

But, I cannot delete a field in the Firestore document.
In another language I know to use `FieldValue.delete()` to delete a file in Firestorm document.

In Dart, How do I delete?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update Oct,2018:** This is Now Possible:

In order to delete a particular field from a Cloud Firestore document - make sure you are using **Plugin version 0.8.0 or Above.** Now a E.g If you have a document having a field 'Desc' with contain some Text. In Order to Delete it.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('path').document('name').update({'Desc': FieldValue.delete()}).whenComplete((){
  print('Field Deleted');
});
```

This will Delete 'Desc' Field from the Document 'name'

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work anymore, I asked a separate question using your code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60759410/error-in-deleting-specific-field-in-a-cloud-firestore-document)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is currently impossible in standard, non hacky way.
There is an open issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13905 in Flutter which have to be resolved first.

Comment: Thanks. This time, I've decided to delete a field using the delete flag.

Comment: How do you delete using the delete flag??

Comment: oh, I don't delete really. if delete flag is true, I just ignore the data. @PhuahYeeKeat

Answer (score 3):

Get the `DocumentReference`, invoke `update` with a map which has a key you want to delete and value `FieldValue.delete()`.

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
collection
  .doc('document_id')
  .update({
    'field_to_delete': FieldValue.delete(),
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an official solution for deleting `Field Path` when programming in `Flutter/Dart`

Here is how a sample Firestore collection looks like:

```
{
   'path': {
      'name': { 
        'title': 'my title'
        'description': 'my description',
       }
   }
}
```

In order to delete `description` field, you can do this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('path').document('name').set(
    {'description': FieldValue.delete()},
    SetOptions(
      merge: true,
    ),
)
```

And the collection will look like this:

```
{
   'path': {
      'name': { 
        'title': 'my title'
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have nested fields then use the '.' (Dot) notation to specify the field.

E.g if your data is nested Map then this is handy.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('path').document('name').update({'address.town': FieldValue.delete()}).whenComplete((){
  print('Field Deleted');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have other question, if I have field with multiple items, like "comments": [cmt1,  cmt2, ...], than how to delete a specific item ?