# Error in deleting specific field in a cloud firestore document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001743/6618622)

```
Firestore.instance.collection('path').document('name').updateData({'Desc': FieldValue.delete()}).whenComplete((){
  print('Field Deleted');
});
```

I'm using

```
 cloud_firestore: 0.13.2+1
```

However, this throws an error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'MethodChannelFieldValue' is not a subtype of type 'FieldValuePlatform'

Can anyone tell me how to delete a field right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0` this seem to working:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance 
    .collection('path')
    .doc('name')
    .update({'desc': FieldValue.delete()});
```